# How Apache CXF technically integrates with Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, frameworks, cxf, integration

I know I could use Apache CXF with Spring by declaring certain CXF beans, but want to know how these framework *technically* integrates with each other.

Does CXF libraries provide some *service provider interface* known to Spring, so Spring scans for this, instantiates the service and takes control of it? Or does CXF implement some other standard mechanism for Spring integration? If so, what is this standard?

Or does CXF library expose Spring annotations / bean declarations to participate in the Spring configuration when in the classpath?

Where I can find the exact sequence of how Spring takes control of CXF from having both of these frameworks on classpath and the necessary configuration to both of them running together? Which configuration is scanned in which side, what API's are called by which and so on.

Answer (score 0):

CXF's is the Bus and its default implementation is SpringBusFactory which scans for certain Spring xml bean configuration files. You can find more information in http://cxf.apache.org/docs/cxf-architecture.html#CXFArchitecture-Bus or by looking at the sourcecode: https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/bus/spring/SpringBusFactory.java